# There is a software who i can download the files from website/server?

Tags: ftp, download, search, website, links

For example i want to download all scans from the "emuparadise..me/magazine-comic-guide-scans/all" and all files is in links. I try the Downthemall and outwit but i cant make it to go to each link to find the download links example: if i put direcly the link "emuparadise..me/magazine-comic-guide-scans/007_From_Russia_With_Love_-_Prima_Official_Guide/2165" they find the pdf files but not from "emuparadise..me/magazine-comic-guide-scans/all". If push the scroll button on mouse on the download link it show "50.7.161.234/998ajxYxajs13jAKhdca/Guides/007%20From%20Russia%20With%20Love%20-%20Prima%20Official%20Guide.pdf". How i can make it to work or how i can make them to search in "50.7.161.234/998ajxYxajs13jAKhdca/Guides/" ????? (i put 2 Telly example..com)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I just want from this website "http://www.emuparadise..me/magazine-comic-guide-scans/all" to download from each link example : "007 Agent Under Fire - Prima Official Guide" "007 Agent Under Fire Xbox GC Prima Official eGuide" and rest of them to download the files in the links from each of them example : from "http://www.emuparadise.me/magazine-comic-guide-scans/007_Agent_Under_Fire_-_Prima_Official_Guide/2221" Direct Download:
007 Agent Under Fire - Prima Official Guide Scan Size: 16.42MB.

Thanks for your time and sorry for my english.

Comment: Or from this ip "50.7.161.234/998ajxYxajs13jAKhdca/Guides/007%20From%20Russia%20With%20Love%20-%20Prima%20Official%20Guide.pdf" to go and search pdf files in this ip.

Answer (score 1):

Try HTTrack, specifically WinHTTrack. It can be quite fiddly to get it working - it's very very aggressive, if you don't clamp down HARD it will fetch URLs from every other domain the site links to - but I'm 99.9% sure it will do what you want. I would recommend you spend a long time fiddling with this program before giving up, I'm certain it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: i have try the HTTrack but it download the website with out the downloadable files.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Huh, that's strange. The only reason I can think HTTrack wouldn't work is if the website encrypted the links with JavaScript. Do you think that might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Use WGET. You'll need Linux and WGET, or [WGET for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

The command you'll need to run:
`wget --user-agent=Mozilla -r -l 1 http://example.com/linkpage`

Comment: where is download the files ?

Comment: I linked WGET for Windows. You need the binaries and the dependencies. The files will be wherever you started the WGET utilities, ex, if you start WGET in `C:\WGET` the downloaded files will be in that directory.